# Unable to click on the Search button using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape the table of the following website (using Python + Selenium):

https://www.ser-ag.com/en/resources/notifications-market-participants/management-transactions.html#/

After I have successfully entered the date parameters in the table, I cannot click the "Search" button via `.click()`. Somehow Selenium does not find the Xpath. Can you help me?

```
# Auf Button suchen klicken
# suchen = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id="")]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]')
# suchen.click()
# time.sleep(2)

button_xpath = "//*[@id='vwHpLbo9TZFKRdgg']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Wait up to 10 seconds
button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of getting that data (all of it):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.ser-ag.com/sheldon/management_transactions/v1/overview.json?pageSize=3000&pageNumber=0&sortAttribute=byDate&fromDate=20220710&toDate=20230710'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['itemList'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    buySellIndicator    correcteeId     correctorId     ISIN    notificationId  notificationSubmitter   notificationSubmitterId     obligorFunctionCode     obligorRelatedPartyInd  securityDescription     securityTypeCode    transactionAmountCHF    transactionConditions   transactionDate     transactionSize     transactionAmountPerSecurityCHF
0   2           CH0019199550    T1N7700039  Alpine Select AG    ALPINE  1   L       7   981.0       20230707    90  10.9
1   1           CH0019199550    T1N7700021  Alpine Select AG    ALPINE  1   L       7   2889.0      20230707    270     10.7
2   1           CH0473243506    T1N7700013  ONE swiss bank SA   SBP     1       Acquisition a la valeur nominale dans le cadre...   7   50000.0     Acquisition en raison de l exercice de stock\n...   20230707    50000   1.0
3   1           CH0022427626    T1N7600015  LEM Holding SA  LEM     2   L       7   108495.0        20230706    50  2169.9
4   1           CH0022427626    T1N7500017  LEM Holding SA  LEM     2   L       7   108660.0        20230705    50  2173.2
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2049    1           CH0019396990    T1M7C00010  Ypsomed Holding AG  YPSOMED     2           7   20100.0         20220712    150     134.0
2050    1   T1M7B00046      CH0023405456    T1M7B00053  DUFRY AG    DUFRY   1   L       7   1980000.0       20220711    60000   33.0
2051    1   T1M7B00012      CH0001341608    T1M7B00061  Hypothekarbank Lenzburg AG  BKHYPOL     1           7   2639.0      20220711    1   2639.0
2052    1           CH0022427626    T1M7B00038  LEM Holding SA  LEM     2   L       7   172570.0        20220711    100     1725.7
2053    2           CH0005059438    T1M7B00020  nebag ag    NEBAG   1           7   32900.0         20220711    3500    9.4

2054 rows × 16 columns
```

Data is being hydrated in page from an API endpoint: you need to scrape that particular endpoint. You can find it by inspecting the Network calls made by the scripts on that page.

Comment: This works! Can you explain a little bit more how you found the API endpoint? How did you get that URL? How did you inspect the Network calls made by the scripts on that page? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @darkwater you start by inspecting the Network tab in browser's Dev tools, and you pay attention to XHR calls (they're under XHR subtab there) -- you check the responses for those calls as well, to see if any of them contains the actual data you're after. I edited the url a bit, changing the number of items returned, so it will bring all 2.5k (I asked for 3K).

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe provide me a link with a tutorial where I can get furter detailed information? And can you judge if your solution method is a bit more robust with respect to the fact that sometimes the websites get modified and the code doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Surely intricate understanding of how a website works is more robust and future-proof, compared to blindly clicking the interface. Also resource-wise it makes more sense. Also, Selenium is not a web scraping framework, it's a testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, probably the reason is button is outside the driver screen, this will "scroll" to button and click, (button code is same on your code)

pd: post your error message please

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
ActionChains(self).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on <kbd>Accept All cookies</kbd> button first, and then try to locate and click <kbd>Search</kbd> button.

See the below working code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.ser-ag.com/en/resources/notifications-market-participants/management-transactions.html#/')
driver.maximize_window()
button_xpath = "//button[text()='Search']"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Wait up to 10 seconds

# Click on Accept All cookies button
Accept_All_Btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Accept_All_Btn)

button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way you can try:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'https://www.ser-ag.com/en/resources/notifications-market-participants/management-transactions.html#/'
driver.get(url)

# wait and click on the "Accept all Cookies" button
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
# wait and click on the "Search" button
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.Button')))[1].click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Things to notice:

- You can locate the <kbd>Search</kbd> button with a simple CSS Selector `button.Button`
- there are two buttons that you get using the selector. The first is the <kbd>Clear Filter</kbd> button and 2nd one is the <kbd>Search</kbd> button.